# Asp.Net.Core MVC fetch data from a view to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am currently doing asp.net.core with MVC model in my project. I want to create an another form to fetch the data from original form.

In my project, the user will choose an item from a list of products, then it will navigate from a view(product.view) to another view (order.view). While what I want is to pass the values (name, description, colour, price, type) from product view to order view.

This is my Order.model

```
namespace FurnitureStore.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureName { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureDescription { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureType { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureColour { get; set; }
        public decimal FurniturePrice { get; set; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my original model

```
namespace FurnitureStore.Models
{
    public class Furniture
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureName { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureDescription { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureType { get; set; }
        public string FurnitureColour { get; set; }
        public decimal FurniturePrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Button-action in first view to Order.View

```
<a asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Buy">Buy</a>
```

Order.View

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="FurnitureName" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="FurnitureName" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="FurnitureName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
//Repeated form-group
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Order.Controller

```
   public ActionResult Buy()
    {

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buy([Bind("OrderID,FurnitureName,FurnitureDescription,FurnitureType,FurnitureColour,FurniturePrice,CustomerName,CustomerContact,CustomerAddress")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to explain a little more what you're trying to achieve in this particular scenario?

Comment: In my project, the user will choose an item from a list of products, then it will navigate from a view(product.view) to another view (order.view). While what I want is to pass the values (name, description, colour, price, type) from product view to order view.

Comment: You'd better give your  first-view code then we could know how and where you pass the data to another view.Have you seen  [asp-route-id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-route-value)?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you need use tag form in your product view, it look something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buy(Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

in your product view

```
<form method="post" asp-area="" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Buy">
        <input name="yourFieldName" type="text">
        <input name="yourFieldName" type="text">
        <input name="yourFieldName" type="text">
        <input name="yourFieldName" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I already did, my request is to fetch the data in the text input from product view to another new order view. After that, the context add and savechanges will be the next step.

Comment: I can't understand you right, you wanna after save redirect to order view?If yes, just use RedirectToAction("Buy")(get buy) where you easy can get data and fill model and return View(Model);

Comment: I think what I what is use viewBag or tempdata to store the text input then pass to another text input but different controller and view. But I have no ideas how to implement it. Sorry for the ambiguous requirements.

Comment: dude i really not understand why you just not pass only id query and then in other action won't get this from entity context.